# How to run your app in production mode on development server in google app engine-java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

**[This link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?csw=1#Java_The_environment)** says whenever we run our app on development server in runs in **Development** mode. Is there any way to run app in **Production** mode without deploying to Google app engine.

Comment: Where in the link does it state it, can't find it?

Comment: seems like this webpage got updated..

Comment: Damn! Well thanks for the fast response, I'm trying to find it. If I do I'll post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer as NO. Development server has its own limitations. To check whether your app is running on Google App engine or not, use below code

```
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
    SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
    // The app is running on App Engine...
}
```

This is taken from [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?csw=1#Java_The_environment), which is mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

No.  But if the only thing you want is remote clients to use your server application, run your [dev_appserver](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver) with the --address=IPADDR command-line argument to override its 127.0.0.1 (localhost) default.  Replace IPADDR with the IP address of your development computer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Well... you could deploy to JBoss using [Cape Dwarf](http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf), but that may not be what you had in mind.

What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am using [gaelic](https://github.com/sosandstrom/gaelic) for my app, i was facing domain name related issue only on production environment i.e. On Google app engine. So i was just thinking how to debug it in development server

Comment: If the problem has something to do with serving infrastructure, as I'm guessing domain name-related issued might be, you're pretty much facing having to debug in place (via admin-protected pages!)