# Local GAE Dev Server and SystemProperty.environment.value()

Tags: google-app-engine

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver

States nowhere about the `SystemProperty.environment.value()` value, what the default setting is, if I can set it etc.. The only info is here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty which states `Global system properties which are set by App Engine.`. As said, what is stated when.

I'm guessing from this question [How to run your app in production mode on development server in google app engine-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346933/how-to-run-your-app-in-production-mode-on-development-server-in-google-app-engin?noredirect=1#comment66526410_21346933) that if a server is started from the sdk the value is development.

It's frustrating to guess this without any official documentation on the matter. Can anyone shed some light on the topic?

Answer (score 1):

This returns an **ENUM** which would either be [Development](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty.Environment.Value#Development) or [Production](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty.Environment.Value#Production). In practice this means the server is running either deployed on Google servers or locally on localhost.

More info on: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty.Environment.Value